# How to check if 2 urls in same domain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urlparse

I was trying to check if 2 urls have same domain using prase.urlparse like this:

```
if parse.urlparse(url1).hostname == parse.urlparse(url2).hostname:
    print('Same Domain')
else:
    print('Different Domain')
```

While this works for: `https://example.com/page1` and `https://example.com/page1`

it doesn't work for: `https://sub1.example.com/page1` and `https://sub2.example.com/page1`

As the returned hostname for first url is `sub1.example.com` and for second url is `https://sub2.example.com/page1`...

What if I only care about main domain and not subdomains?

I want to retrive `example.com` alone without manually parsing the url as a string but rather use libraries for such cases like parse.urlprase.